# Rotate other logs with rotatelogs.exe

Tags: windows, log-files, rotation

On my machine there is some process which is writing a log in C:\Application.log. Now I want to rotate the logs file without stopping that application. On the same machine I have apache 2.2. As I know we can use apache's rotatelogs.exe, but it is not rotating the log file

I am using following syntax to rotate the log file:

```
C:\Apache\bin\rotatelogs.exe  C:\Application.log 20M
```

Need expert opinion to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html

> rotatelogs is a simple program for use in conjunction with Apache's
>   piped logfile feature

This means that to use rotate logs the application you have must have the ability log to a pipe, be configured to send the logs to the `rotatelogs` stdin.